# How can I use a Drupal 6 database in Drupal 7 without upgrading that database?

Tags: upgrading

I am new in Drupal. Currently I am working on one project where I am using Drupal 7.12. My client had one project in Drupal 6 of which database he wants to use in the Drupal 7 project. I can not upgrade the Drupal 6 to 7 as it's a completely different instance but he wants to have same userbase and other things in the new project i.e Drupal 7. As per knowledge DB structure of Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 is very different and hence it's not going to be very easy to use the Drupal 6 DB in 7.

Please suggest me any way to use Drupal 6 DB in 7.

Comment: The same way you can use diesel in a petrol engine - it'll do _something_, but not what you want

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, you cannot unless you are willing to rewrite a *lot* of Drupal 7 parts.

One thing you can do, is to implement cron jobs to export changes in version-independent format like XML on source site, and import them from XML at target site.

Alternatively, you can use [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module and make one page call the other to perform certain tasks, like user login or article reading.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You gave a clue to start working on it. Thanks

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar What can I say, read about services and about XML modules, and choose your way.